# How does cron job work in the background?

Tags: cron, daemon

Say, I have scheduled a script to run after every 3 mins. The Cron job runs the script first time and now, after 3 mins. it will try to run the script again, but the script is already running from the first instance and that the processing is still not complete. What will happen than - will it run the script again as a second instance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes (unless the script itself takes measures to prevent a second instance from running).

Cron just runs a command on a schedule.

If that command starts a program, it starts a program.

Comment: Ok Thanks. This explains everything.